# Facebook game in Unity: Leaderboards work for Test Users, but not for real accounts

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, permissions, leaderboard, publish-actions

I've made a game for Facebook which has a leaderboard so people can compare their best scores.

It works perfectly in the Unity editor with Test User logins. When I view the leaderboard all of the test users appear with the correct scores, but when I try it with my own account, I'm the only one on the board and my score always displays as 0 (I have a friend added as a tester, and she also only sees her own score of 0 on the board)

When I try logging in as myself in the Unity editor, the same thing happens, but I get the following error:

Score submit result: {"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

But I've already included publish_actions in my game, and it's even been submitted and approved by Facebook, but still doesn't work :(

I'm guessing this is just a problem on Facebook's end, but is there anything I can do? I'm new to publishing to FB :(

Thanks for reading and I appreciate any help!

Chel

Answer (score 0):

It seems your player have declined to give the permission for your app. It can certainly happen.

You can read more about how to check which permissions are granted and below that how to handle them if they are missing on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v1.0#checking). The general idea is that you should catch this error and handle it within your app so if a player decides to not grant your app sufficient permissions for posting on their FB page then your app should skip that part of the code entirely.

Hope this helps in finetuning your app.